# How to change one keyword's color in Geany?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, self, geany

I use Geany to edit JavaScript files. I have made it highlight "self" as a keyword symply by adding it to filetypes.javascript file.
But i need to make it highlighth "self" word in another color. How can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Linux, copy the file `/usr/share/geany/filedefs/filetypes.javascript` to `~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.javascript` and edit this copy.

In the section [keywords] add:

```
secondary=self
```

Change the colour in section [styling] by editing word2, e.g.:

```
word2=0x00cccc;0xffffff;true;false
```

This will make it cyan and bold.

Comment: Hello - Is there documentation on the geany colorscheme .conf format? (Especially a list of all the possible sections and values?) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit your filetypes.javascript file (in folder $/.config/.geany, if you're under linux). But I am not 100% sure you can.